# How to show a custom view above Action Bar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Screenshot from google music app:

[image]

I have these **two questions**:

**1.** How element like this is called and how can I implement something like this?

**2.** How they can it be above the action bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple way to achieve this. ActionBar keeps its layout in the class **ActionBarContainer** which simply **inherits** from **FrameLayout**. So in order **to display something over the ActionBar** you need to **grab a reference to the ActionBarContaine**r and add your **own custom View** into it. Here is the code

```
// first get the id of Action bar container    
    int actionbarContainerViewID = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_container", "id", "android");     
    FrameLayout actionBarContainer = (FrameLayout)findViewById(actionbarContainerViewID);

// bring the layout inflator to inflate your custom layout      
    LayoutInflater mInflater = getLayoutInflater();        
    View customView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourCustomDesign, null);
    actionBarContainer.addView(customView);
```

**you won't be needing any special way to put it over the top! just design it as you like and it will be on the top!**